# gettimeofday() microsecond not limited to below second

Tags: c, time, gettimeofday

When I output the microseconds field for `gettimeofday()`, I notice that the microsecond field is larger than 1,000,000. Does anyone know why this is? And does this imply that I've been interpreting `gettimeofday()` wrong?

For the record, my assumption is that the current time (in microseconds) according to `gettimeofday()` is the following:

```
struct timeval ts;
gettimeofday(&ts, NULL); 
printf("%zu", ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_usec);
```

Edit: Here is the code that is causing the problem. After the comments below, the printf() might be at fault.

```
struct timeval curr_time;
gettimeofday(&curr_time, NULL);
printf("Done-arino! Onto the matrix multiplication (at %zu s, %03zu ms)\n", curr_time.tv_sec, curr_time.tv_usec);

// Matrix Multiplication
struct timeval start_tv, end_tv, elapsed_tv;
gettimeofday(&start_tv, NULL);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
gettimeofday(&end_tv, NULL);
timersub(&end_tv, &start_tv, &elapsed_tv);

// Print results
printf("Elapsed time: %zu s, %03zu ms\n", elapsed_tv.tv_sec, elapsed_tv.tv_usec / 1000);
```

Comment: You'll need to identify your platform more carefully, and show us an MCVE ([MCVE]) that demonstrates the problem.  What you show does not demonstrate that `tv_usec` is equal to or greater than one million, which is what you're claiming.  As noted below, you are correct that `tv_usec` should be less than one million.

Comment: Your suspicion that `tv_usec` should be less than 1000000 is correct.  And I'd be very surprised to see `tv_usec` greater than or equal  to 1000000 (with one exception, which does not apply here).  Can you tell us more about your sighting of a greater-than-1000000 value?

Comment: More convincing code might be: `int main(void) { while (1) { struct timeval ts; if (gettimeofday(&ts, 0) == 0 && ts.tv_usec >= 1000000) printf("%lu s; %lu µs\n", (long)ts.tv_sec, (long)ts.tv_usec); } return 0; }`.

Comment: One sec, posting my code soon.

Comment: You need to show `timersub()` — though it might be provided by the system, in which case you need to identify the system.  But nothing in your code demonstrates that `gettimeofday()` is wrong.  You've not printed a value of `tv_usec` that is more than 999,999.

Comment: timersub is a provided function in sys/time.h. I'm running on linux. What other details about my system do you need to know?

Answer (score 2):

After a successful to `gettimeofday`, yes, `tv_usec` is guaranteed to be strictly less than 1000000.

If you (think you) saw a value of 1000000 or greater, then yes, it's likely you were doing something wrong.

A frequent mistake is to add or subtract two `struct timeval` values naively, without implementing proper carry or borrow between the `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` fields, and this can easily lead to (mistaken and wrong) values in `tv_usec` greater than 1000000.  (In your edited post you mention subtracting timespecs, but you're using the system-supplied `timersub` function which ought to get the borrow right.)

If you were using a `struct timespec` instead of `struct timeval`, and *if* a leap second were going on, and *if* you were (miraculously) using an OS kernel that implemented the `CLOCK_UTC` clock type proposed by Markus Kuhn at https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/posix-clocks.html, you'd see `tv_nsec` values greater than 1000000000, but that's a lot of "if"s.  (And to my knowledge no kernel in widespread use has ever implemented `CLOCK_UTC`.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to show some more convincing code, and identify the platform on which you run into the problem.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct timeval ts;
        if (gettimeofday(&ts, 0) == 0 && ts.tv_usec >= 1000000)
            printf("%lu s; %lu µs\n", (long)ts.tv_sec, (long)ts.tv_usec); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The very busy loop is a tad irksome; maybe you should use `nanosleep()` to sleep for a microsecond or two on every iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        if (gettimeofday(&tv, 0) == 0 && tv.tv_usec >= 1000000)
            printf("%lu s; %lu µs\n", (long)tv.tv_sec, (long)tv.tv_usec); 
        struct timespec ts = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 2000 };
        nanosleep(&ts, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or, including a progress meter to demonstrate that the code is running:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        size_t loop_count = 0;
        size_t line_count = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            struct timeval tv;
            if (gettimeofday(&tv, 0) == 0 && tv.tv_usec >= 1000000)
                printf("%lu s; %lu µs\n", (long)tv.tv_sec, (long)tv.tv_usec); 
            struct timespec ts = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 2000 };
            nanosleep(&ts, 0);
            if (++loop_count > 100000)
            {
                loop_count = 0;
                putchar('.');
                line_count++;
                if (line_count >= 50)
                {
                    putchar('\n');
                    line_count = 0;
                }
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

#### `timersub()`

On an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM, I can find file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h` containing a macro:

```
# define timersub(a, b, result)                                               \
  do {                                                                        \
    (result)->tv_sec = (a)->tv_sec - (b)->tv_sec;                             \
    (result)->tv_usec = (a)->tv_usec - (b)->tv_usec;                          \
    if ((result)->tv_usec < 0) {                                              \
      --(result)->tv_sec;                                                     \
      (result)->tv_usec += 1000000;                                           \
    }                                                                         \
  } while (0)
```

<s>All the indications I can see are that `tv_usec` is an `__u32`, an unsigned quantity.</s>  If that's the case, then the `< 0` condition will never be true and you may sometimes see grotesquely large positive values instead.  YMMV, of course.

**Even my mileage varies**

Further scrutiny shows that while there are headers that seem to use `__u32` for `tv_usec`, those are not the main system headers.

```
/usr/include/linux/time.h:  __kernel_suseconds_t     tv_usec;   /* microseconds */
/usr/include/linux/can/bcm.h:   long tv_usec;
/usr/include/drm/exynos_drm.h:  __u32           tv_usec;
/usr/include/drm/exynos_drm.h:  __u32           tv_usec;
/usr/include/drm/vmwgfx_drm.h:  uint32_t tv_usec;
/usr/include/drm/drm.h: __u32 tv_usec;
/usr/include/rpc/auth_des.h:    uint32_t tv_usec;           /* Microseconds.  */
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-darwin.h:#define vki_tv_usec tv_usec
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-linux.h:  vki_suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
/usr/include/rpcsvc/rstat.x:    unsigned int tv_usec;   /* and microseconds */
/usr/include/rpcsvc/rstat.h:    u_int tv_usec;
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/utmpx.h:    __int32_t tv_usec;       /* Microseconds.  */
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h:    __suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* Microseconds.  */
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/utmp.h:    int32_t tv_usec;      /* Microseconds.  */
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:   (ts)->tv_nsec = (tv)->tv_usec * 1000;                           \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:   (tv)->tv_usec = (ts)->tv_nsec / 1000;                           \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:# define timerisset(tvp)   ((tvp)->tv_sec || (tvp)->tv_usec)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:# define timerclear(tvp)   ((tvp)->tv_sec = (tvp)->tv_usec = 0)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:   ((a)->tv_usec CMP (b)->tv_usec) :                         \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:    (result)->tv_usec = (a)->tv_usec + (b)->tv_usec;                 \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:    if ((result)->tv_usec >= 1000000)                        \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:   (result)->tv_usec -= 1000000;                         \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:    (result)->tv_usec = (a)->tv_usec - (b)->tv_usec;                 \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:    if ((result)->tv_usec < 0) {                         \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:      (result)->tv_usec += 1000000;                          \
```

It's worrying to see any code using an unsigned type for a member with that name, but that doesn't mean it is happening for code using `struct timeval` and `timersub()`.

This code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = -1 };
    printf("%ld %ld\n", (long)t.tv_sec, (long)t.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled for 64-bit (so `long` is big enough to hold anything that `tv_usec` could be defined as) prints `0 -1` as it should.  It would be possible to initialize the `tv_usec` member to `0`, decrement it, and verify that it is negative, and various other related tests.

So, the problem isn't as simple as "`timersub()` is wrong" — which is an immense relief.

Comment: What details about the platform do you need to know?

Comment: Well, its species (Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, macOS, Mac OS X, AIX, Windows), probably its version, the hardware, the library version, etc.  Basically, it is improbable that you've run into a bug in `gettimeofday()`, so the onus is on you to validate your claim that you've seen `tv_usec >= 1000000` on some system by printing the value, and showing the code that prints the value.  Or, by showing the code in `timersub()` if you wrote it (but the raw data will be more convincing than the output from a computational function), or ... Basically, at the moment, your contention is pure anecdote.

Comment: @Fire3galaxy Linux distro, Linux kernel version (`cat /proc/sys/version`), glibc version.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer, that's fair. Right now, I can't provide those details since it's not my machine (and I need to go). I can show the output I saw, but I think at this point, I'll consider the case closed (can't seem to reproduce it now).

Comment: @Fire3galaxy Time-related code is notoriously difficult to get right, and there are some fascinating subtleties.  If you're still having difficulties when you're back at this, feel free to ping us.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  Consider running one of the bits of code I show.  I've been running it without the `nanosleep()` on a Mac for multiple minutes without running into the problem (I used 10,000,000 instead of 100,000 for the repeat).  But in all honesty, I don't think you'll see the problem with `gettimeofday()` alone.  You might see it from `timersub()` — that would be a separate issue, of course.

Comment: Looks like it's probably a printf format problem.  See [my second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547661/gettimeofday-microsecond-not-limited-to-below-second/50547844#50547844).

Comment: @SteveSummit: Possibly.  Possibly a bug in `timersub()` — see my extension to my only answer :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yikes.  I've got some time code of my own where I very specifically made the subsec types signed (even though I wanted to declare them unsigned, to document that they'd always be positive), precisely to make it easier to write the subtraction code.  I'm astonished if any version of glibc is getting this wrong..

Comment: @SteveSummit: Me too ("astonished that any version of glibc is getting this wrong").  But the blame is now being pointed to a more plausible candidate.  POSIX [`<sys/types.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) requires _[XSI] ⌦ The type **suseconds_t** shall be a signed integer type capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, 1000000].⌫_  I need to go verify that `tv_usec` is unsigned.

Comment: @SteveSummit: _[…time passes…]_ a closer look at the headers shows that the ones with `__u32` for `tv_usec` aren't the main system headers.  And the main header does, I think, have a signed type as it should.

Comment: @SteveSummit: And another update — the main code gets a clean bill of health, though I worry about those other headers that do use an unsigned `tv_usec`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Once upon a time -- I'm sure you remember those days, too -- a common data structure was defined in *one* place, in *one* file.  But that was too easy, too simple, I guess...  (In other words, I share your... concern... about those other, incompatible definitions.  What would Dennis say?)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes — I'm sure that if one could harness the spinning, it would generate megawatts!

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf` formats are suspect, and could be causing this problem.

The `%zu` format is for printing `size_t` values.  But neither `tv_sec` nor `tv_usec` has type `size_t`.

On a modern system, `size_t` is likely to be 64 bits.  But if either `tv_sec` or `tv_usec` is not, `printf` will end up printing those values quite wrongly.

I changed your `printf`s to

```
printf("Done-arino! Onto the matrix multiplication (at %ld s, %03u ms)\n",
        curr_time.tv_sec, curr_time.tv_usec);
```

and

```
printf("Elapsed time: %ld s, %03u ms\n",
        elapsed_tv.tv_sec, elapsed_tv.tv_usec / 1000);
```

These won't necessarily be correct for you, though — it depends on your system's specific choices for `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`.

The general and portable way to print a value of an implementation-defined type like this is to explicitly cast it to the largest type it can be, then use the `printf` format corresponding to the cast-to type.  For example:

```
printf("Done-arino! Onto the matrix multiplication (at %ld s, %03ld ms)\n",
        (long)curr_time.tv_sec, (long)curr_time.tv_usec);

printf("Elapsed time: %ld s, %03ld ms\n",
        (long)elapsed_tv.tv_sec, (long)elapsed_tv.tv_usec / 1000);
```

The cast might or might not be a no-op, but the point is that, no matter what the original type was, you end up with something that matches what you've told `printf` to expect.